Golang GORM Recursive Structure Migration (MySQL)
I'm trying to create a recursive table structure, but I have not had any luck. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:
package models

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Entity struct {
    gorm.Model
    Level        int     `json:"level"`
    Parent       *Entity `json:"parent" gorm:"foreignKey:ParentID`
    Name         string  `json:"name"`
    InheritGroup int     `json:"inherit_group"`
}

However, when running migrations with db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{}, &models.Entity{}, &models.UserEntity{}), I keep getting this error: invalid field found for struct x/x/database/models.Entity's field Parent: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface.
I've seen a couple of rough solutions, all of which don't work well or at all. I'm wondering if there is a clean solution that would allow me to preload and query to retrieve all entities. If there is a better way that would allow me to query for a top-level entity and populate in the children (if you can't tell already, I'm definitely more familiar with MongoDB), I would be open to that as well.

This is not a mysql error message, so you need to figure out a gorm way of doing it. There is a canonical question for mysql for hierarchical queries if you want to go down a native sql way.
